# Linq query to call webservice in the where clause

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, linq-to-entities

Given the following types

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
public interface IMyService
{
    bool IsNameCool(string name);
}
```

I need to implement something like that

```
public class CoolUsersFinder
{
    IMyService _myService;
    private Context _context;

    public CoolUsersFinder(IMyService myService, Context context)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<long> GetIdsOfCoolUsers()
    {
        return ???
    }
}
```

while IMyService is implemented in a webservice, and i don't know how its implementations looks like, and i want to implement GetIdsOfCoolUsers method to return something looks like that

```
return context.Users.Where(U => myService.IsNameCool(U.Name) ).Select(U.ID).ToList()
```

While my database is really huge and i cannot get all records at once and filter them later, i need the translated code to SQL to be able to filter the data.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Does `IMyService` have an option that dumps details about all "cool" users? Otherwise even if the database accessed it directly, it would still have to be a row-by-row hit.

Comment: Actually, i don't have any details about `IMyService` itself as it can be changed from time to time.

And i have about 100,000+ of records, which will cost time to retrieve all records from DB and process the data in my C# code.

Answer (score 0):

if the way you decide if a name is cool or not does not change, you can add it as column to the users table and update it when users are added or updated.
the it will be very easy to get all the cool users.

even if the way you decide if a name is cool or not changes you only need to re-calculate it once for all the users.